# Get IndexPath of the cell which I clicked after opening the photo library and selecting a photo to set up this photo in the clicked cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I've a tableView with dynamic cells. Each section has 5 rows. In the fifth row there is a button and an imageview. When (at runtime) I click on the button, I can choose a photo from my photo library. The image should be put in imageview. This doesn't happen because I can't get the indexPath of the cell which I clicked the button to add a photo. The number of sections is decided at run-time using a stepper.

[image]

Here the code that will be executed when I click on the button (to open the photo library)

```
//method connected to the selected button photo
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take a photo",@"Pick from library", nil];
    [self getIndexPathAtSection:sender];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self shootPictureOrVideo];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1){
        [self selectExistingPictureOrVideo];
    }
}
#pragma mark - CAMERA AND PHOTO LIBRARY    
- (void)pickMediaFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
    {
    NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:sourceType];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType] && [mediaTypes count]>0){
        NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:sourceType];
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = sourceType;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error accessing media" message:@"Device doesn't support that media source" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Drat!" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];


    }
}


- (UIImage *)shrinkImage:(UIImage *)original toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0);
    [original drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *final = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return final;
}

- (void)shootPictureOrVideo
{
    [self pickMediaFromSource:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
- (void)selectExistingPictureOrVideo
{
    [self pickMediaFromSource:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}


#pragma mark - IMPAGE PICKER CONTROLLER DELEGATE

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellProfileSnap";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:_indexForPicker];
    UIImageView *imgViewPhoto = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:4];
    _lastChosenMediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    UIImage *shrunkenImage = [self shrinkImage:chosenImage toSize:imgViewPhoto.bounds.size];
    imgViewPhoto.image = shrunkenImage;
    NSLog(@"%ld - %ld %ld",(long)_indexForPicker.row,(long)imgViewPhoto.tag,(long)cell.tag);

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (void)getIndexPathAtSection:(id)sender{

    UITableViewCell *uhm = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellProfileSnap"];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:uhm];
    _indexForPicker = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)_indexForPicker.row);
}
```

The _indexPathForPicker is always 0.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `NSIndexPath` of the `UITableViewCell` selected by implementing the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method.

When you touch that cell to add a photo, it will fire that method. You can then access the row via the `indexPath.row` argument.

*edit*

You should also not dequeue a cell yourself. You should acquire a cell by using tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Change

```m
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:_indexForPicker];
```

to

```m
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
```

Comment: Ok. And why when I add a new section (by stepper), the content of the cells in a section mixes with content of another section?

Comment: It sounds like you are not properly managing your data source. The data in each section should be stored in their own NSArray to help segregate them if you are not already doing that. Somewhere in your code logic you are not properly pulling data from the datasource associated to each section